# How to put files into the res folder of ready to use apk?

Tags: android, batch-file, zip, 7zip

I have such an issue: I have some test.apk file. There is res folder with all graphics resources. I need to write .bat file for artists to do next: 
1. take resources from external folder and replace current resources with new and re-pack apk file.

There are such files in apk:

```
assets META-INF res AndroidManifest.xml classes.dex resources.arsc
```

**So, as far as I understood the task I need to:**

1. Copy 1.apk to 1.zip
2. Unzip 1.zip to 1 folder
3. Remove "res" folder and put there my own folder
4. Create new 1.apk file and sign it with my certificate. Done.

**I have 2 questions:**

1. How to zip/unzip file with batch commands?
2. How to sign my new folder with new certificate?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to update image resources in an already packaged APK? Is re-packaging a signed APK not an option? Do you not have the source code?

Comment: So you think I can get let's say Google+ app, change resources with my own images and strings and upload it as Ics+ in pink? Really?

Comment: 2 Alex Fu: I have the source code. Buy artists from my team - have no. And we have a problem with that they providing us bad resources. So we want to give them a little tool - that they have ability to test images themselves firsly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem! Here is solution, maby someone will find it usefull. Commands of bat file.

**You need to have: 7zip archive program, Android SDK, JDK 1.7.**

Links to resources used to make this:
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html

```
SET app_input_file_name=%1
SET tmp_app_name="tmp_app_name.zip"
SET zip_tool_path="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
```

rem 1. Create copy of AndroidSampleApp.apk and rename it with AndroidSapmleApp.zip

```
copy %app_input_file_name% %tmp_app_name%
```

rem 2. Extract folder res/ from AndroidSapmleApp.zip file to root folder.

```
%zip_tool_path% x %tmp_app_name% res/
```

rem 3. Remove META-INF and res folders.

```
%zip_tool_path% d %tmp_app_name% res
%zip_tool_path% d %tmp_app_name% META-INF
```

**After making changes to resources to next:**

```
SET app_output_file_name=%1
SET tmp_app_name="tmp_app_name.zip"
SET dev_certificate="mycert.keystore"
SET dev_certificate_alias="mycert"
SET zip_tool_path="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
SET jarsigner_tool_path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\jarsigner.exe"
SET zipalign_tool_path="D:\SDKs\android-sdk_r18-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools\zipalign.exe"
```

rem 4. Make changes in extracted res folder, you can not remove or add any new files!! Only change images.
rem 5. Add modified res/ folder to AndroidSapmleApp.zip with copmress method Store.

```
%zip_tool_path% a %tmp_app_name% res -mx0
```

rem 6. Remove res/ folder

```
rmdir res /s /q
```

rem 7. Rename AndroidSapmleApp.zip to AndroidSapmleApp.apk

```
copy %tmp_app_name% %app_output_file_name%
```

rem 8. Sign application with your certificate mycert.keystore

```
%jarsigner_tool_path% -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore %dev_certificate% %app_output_file_name% %dev_certificate_alias%
```

rem 9. Verify is it all ok

```
%jarsigner_tool_path% -verify %app_output_file_name%
```

rem 10. zipalign on *.apk:

```
%zipalign_tool_path% -v -f 4 %app_output_file_name%
```

rem 11. Remove old app: adb uninstall com.partypoker.poker

```
rem adb uninstall com.packagename
```

rem 12. Install app to simulator/device.

```
rem adb install AndroidSapmleApp.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP is not trying to "steal" someone else's App.  He is trying to separate the process of writing the Java code from the process of creating the graphics, and let the graphics creation process happen AFTER the Java code is compiled.  This is a perfectly reasonable thing to want to do -- but is likely to be exceptionally difficult if not impossible..

The problem is the resources in an apk have been compiled by aapt into an internal format.  The replacements must also be in this internal format. However, during the compilation process aapt produces the R class defining the resource ID's.  This R class must be available to the Java compiler so that the compiled dex files will use the correct resource ID's.

The drawing here: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html shows this in graphic format.

A revised workflow which might work:

Java developers using placeholder graphics build the application up to, but not including the apkbuilder step.

- Graphic developers create the pretty pictures -- restricting themselves to the preexisting placehold graphics (i.e. edit them but do not add new ones or remove old ones.)
- The batch file runs aapt -- it must have access to the entire original res directory to insure that the generated ID's match.
- The batch file runs apkbuilder to produce the unsigned apk.
- The apk is then zipaligned, proguarded and signed as necessary.

The best way to set this up is probably start with an existing Ant build script and create a new Ant build script to support the desired workflow.

...um ... good luck....

Comment: Thanks for complete answer, but I want to replace only "uncompiled resources". Is it possible in easier way?